# List() function does not convert a string into the expected list

Tags: python, python-2.7, list

I'm taking a Python class at my school and while doing a homework assignment, I encountered something strange.

If I give a string beginning with `0` as an input, the list is not created correctly (code below). For example, if I give `'000000'` for input , `['0']` is printed out instead of `['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0']`. Furthermore, if I give `'000111'` as an input , `['7', '3']`  prints out. Is there a reason why the created list is not the expected? The code is running on Repl.it in Python version 2.7.10 if that helps.

```
variable = list(str(input('')))
print(variable)
```

I was expecting the output of inputting `'000000'` to be `['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0']` but the actual output is `['0']`

Comment: Did you try to debug this at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `input()` function in python-2 takes input as python code. This means that '00000' was reached as 0 for execution (since 00000 was taken as int and its value is 0). Thus you should consider using raw_input() instead of input().

```
>>> var = list(str(raw_input("")))
00000
>>> print(var)
['0', '0', '0', '0', '0']
```

Well for python-3 there is no such thing as raw_input(); because input() replaced it.

Also; in python-2; non-zero decimal numbers with leading Zeros are not allowed. Because they are treated as octal numbers and thus are converted to the decimal number system. This thing was removed in version 3 of python.  [See here for docs referal](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#integer-literals)

```
# python-2 interpreter
>>> max(0345, 344)
344    # since 345(of octal) in decimal number system is 229
```

And this was the reason why 000111 was treated as `73` and then when you did `str()` and then `list()` on it; it became `['7','3']`.